# Find and rename illegal characters with mac terminal

Tags: command-line, automation, macos

Since mac doesn't support certain characters like ?!# ... on server directories anymore, I need to find and rename those. There are tons of "Icon?"-files in font folders and I want to rename it to "Icon_"

I tried to do it with terminal since other apps like "a better finder rename" have difficulties to find certain characters like "?" in filenames like my example "Icon?".

My first try was the `find` command like this:

`find . -exec rename -s "Icon?" "Icon_" * {} +`

It says "Unknown option: F"

Comment: You are using the wrong quote characters, use `"` or `'`. Also, if some characters are not allowed, how would trying to rename these files even work? AFAIK the file system handles these translations automatically, so which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Also, '?' has special meaning when used to match filenames

Comment: I have problems to make backups of the servers data. The backup-app errors with those characters. Thanks for the hint with the quotes, your are right, I made the mistake only here in the questions. It's now edited.

Comment: @ nohillside What special meanings does "?" have?

Comment: What is the * supposed to do here? And should‘t you search fore files called 'Icon?' only and just rename those (instead of trying to rename all files)?

Comment: ? matches any single character in pattern matches.

Comment: Anyway, renaming these files will render them useless, you could as well just delete them. But I still think you are trying to fix the symptoms instead of the root cause.

Comment: Sorry I don't have in depth knowledge of terminal commands. I was not aware that I rename all files. I thought i was searching only for 'Icon?' files. How do you think the command should look like?

Comment: According to our technician the root cause is, that apple changed some "format" how it is dealing with server files. Characters which were ok in earlier years are now a problem. That is why we have to get rid of all those characters. I know that is a workaround, but I don't see an other way to do it.

Comment: The files are there for a reason. If you rename them, the application looking for them won't find them any longer.

Comment: As for the command: which parameters does your version of `rename` take?

Comment: Usage:
    rename [switches|transforms] [files]

    Switches:

    --man (read the full manual)
    -0/--null (when reading from STDIN)
    -f/--force or -i/--interactive (proceed or prompt when overwriting)
    -g/--glob (expand "*" etc. in filenames, useful in Windows™ CMD.EXE)
    -k/--backwards/--reverse-order
    -l/--symlink or -L/--hardlink
    -M/--use=*Module*
    -n/--just-print/--dry-run
    -N/--counter-format
    -p/--mkpath/--make-dirs
    --stdin/--no-stdin
    -t/--sort-time
    -T/--transcode=*encoding*
    -v/--verbose

Comment: Transforms, applied sequentially:

    -a/--append=*str*
    -A/--prepend=*str*
    -c/--lower-case
    -C/--upper-case
    -d/--delete=*str*
    -D/--delete-all=*str*
    -e/--expr=*code*
    -P/--pipe=*cmd*
    -s/--subst *from* *to*
    -S/--subst-all *from* *to*
    -x/--remove-extension
    -X/--keep-extension
    -z/--sanitize
    --camelcase --urlesc --nows --rews --noctrl --nometa --trim (see manual)

Comment: We use our server only for data storage. There are no applications running on it. The Icon?-files are some strange files in font-folders which we have many.

Comment: Uhh, can you just show one example of how to use `rename` to rename one specific file?

Comment: And I still don't get it: Something put these Icon? files into the folders. If this something needs them, renaming them will break things.

Comment: Just for the record, the chars you specified “?!#” can be used for both filenames and directories.  In fact, since unix filenames are stored as arrays of bytes and not characters, with the exception of a small handful of chars, you can use pretty much anything.  See: [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459469/119271). That said, there seems to be a different issue here to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh (the shell in mac terminal), you can replace a part of a variable using parameter expansion.

You could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090087) to [Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086502/4424636), with bash shell command. It would be useful in zsh too.

`cd` to your target directory, then use:

`for f in Icon?* do mv "$f" "${f/Icon?/Icon_}"; done`

Since shell command is unforgiving, echo (print) it before you mv (give a new name to) it:

`for f in Icon?* do echo "$f" "${f/Icon?/Icon_}"; done`