# Open .webloc file with colons in its name using "open"

Tags: terminal, command-line

Suppose I have a file `~/Desktop/foo:bar.webloc`.

(a) If I double-click it, it opens a particular web page. Great!

(b) If in the Terminal I run `open ~/Desktop/foo:bar.webloc`, it opens the webpage. Great!

(c) If in the Terminal I run `cd Desktop` and then `open foo:bar.webloc`, I am greeted with

```
% open foo:bar.webloc 
foo:bar.webloc?
[0] cancel
[1] Open the file foo:bar.webloc
[2] Open the URL  foo:bar.webloc

Which did you mean?
```

I'm guessing that `open` thinks that the filename might be a URL. Is there some way to force `open` to open the file by default if the file exists, even if the file name matches a pattern that could conceivably be a URL? Kind of the opposite of `open -u`?  Do I just need to avoid colons in filenames?

This arose because Firefox created a filename containing a colon when I dragged from the URL bar to the desktop, and then I tried to open it from the Terminal. Maybe another question is: is there a way to automatically get colon-free filenames when creating webloc files? (If you want to test, you can use the URL https://github.com/sagemath/trac-to-github/blob/master/docs/Migration-Trac-to-Github.md. Safari and Chrome produce colon-free filenames, but not Firefox.)

Edit: based on case (b), a partial workaround is to use `open ./foo:bar.webloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm guessing that open thinks that the filename might be a URL.

You would be correct in that guess.

Unix/BSD/Linux/etc. ([macOS is a certified Unix](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/apple.htm)) don’t use characters for filenames.  Instead, it’s an array of bytes. With the exception of a few characters like the `Null` character (0x00) and forward slash (0x2f - `/`) pretty much everything else is fair game *including* colons.  In short, you can have colons in your filename and it be valid.

See this excellent post on Unix & Linux entitled [Understanding Unix File Name Encoding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39175/107777) for additional details.

> Is there some way to force open to open the file by default if the file exists,

Unfortunately, no.  Your operating system (macOS in this case) cannot tell the difference between a filename with a colon or a URL with a colon.

Why?

The problem here is that per the URL Specification ([RFC-1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)), **§2.1, The main parts of URLs** define what a URL is supposed to look like…

> A URL contains the name of the scheme being used () **followed by a colon** and then a string (the ) whose interpretation depends on the scheme.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

> if the file name matches a pattern that could conceivably be a URL?

A file is a file; that’s easy.  A URL on the other hand, can be many things, *including* a file.  See RFC-1738 **§3.10 Files**:

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes, does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the Internet.

A file URL can take the form of (VAX/VMS):

```
DISK$USER:[SHARE]FOO.BAR
         ꜛ
          Note the colon!
```

That’s a perfectly valid file and in this case, would be remote.  However, due to how Unix allows every single one of the those characters to exist in a filename, the question (for the OS) is “how to handle it?”  Open as a URL or open as a file?  This is why you get the prompt.

#### TL;DR

You can’t force `open` to open a target as a file when the argument can be one of many things.  In this case, a file with a colon could be either URL or it could be a file; thus the prompt you are seeing.

This is due to the “permissible characters” (byte arrays, actually) that make up a filename on Unix as well as the confusion created behind what a URL is defined as.

As for a “reverse” of `open -u`, well, that just doesn’t exist as an argument for the `open` command.

Comment: It seems odd that there is `open -u` which forces `open` to view the argument as a URL, even if the argument also matches a filename, but there is no complementary flag to force it to choose the filename.

Comment: Note that on OS X, apparently in contrast with VAX/VMS, `foo$bar:baz.webloc` is viewed as a filename rather than a URL, I think because `$` is not an allowed character in a scheme name.

Answer (score 5):

The current directory can be referenced using the directory name `.`. So use

```
open ./foo:bar.webloc
```

This is not a valid URL, so it's treated as a filename.

This is also a common way to deal with filenames that begin with `-`, which might otherwise be interpreted as command options.

Comment: Right, I added that as an edit to my post a few hours ago.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that until after I posted my answer. So I added the additional part about filenames with `-`.

Comment: You could of course have posted that as an answer yourself. Solutions are supposed to be in answers, not the question itself.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. It's not actually a useful answer for me, just a workaround, and I didn't think to post it as an answer: I really want to be able to use this in Emacs, in its `dired` mode: basically you choose a file, hit a key, and run a command on it. Typically `open` works, but typing in `open` followed by the full filename is not practical. I could do some emacs-lisp hacking to take care of it, but to be honest, it's a rare situation and probably easiest to just rename the file to avoid colons.